# What is the meaning of the --pod-network-cidr flag in kubeadm?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

kubeadm, the official kubernetes installer, takes a `--pod-cidr-network` flag as a flag in the `init` command. This translates to the `--cluster-cidr` flag of kube-controller-manager.

But it seems that this value is not really used. For example, I've passed the value -`192.168.0.0/16` , but when I'm running pods in the cluster, I can see that they get IPs outside of this range.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/) documentation:

```
--cluster-cidr string
CIDR Range for Pods in cluster. Requires --allocate-node-cidrs to be true
```

If  the CIDR range you set is not applied, it's probably because you have to also set the `--allocate-node-cidrs` flag to true.